# asm.js limits on the compiler

Tags: javascript, performance, compiler-construction, emscripten

I would like to know if there are any "limits by design" on the asm.js spec that would prevent any compiler to produce native assembly code directly from it.

For now firefox seems to be able to be half as fast as native code but I'm wondering why it does not run at native speed. As I see it, asm.js resembles asm a lot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is currently using the `Typed Array` types of Javascript as memory (*stack* and *heap* that is). This is due to other scripts interacting with your asm.js generated Javascript, and needing a shared "memory" space.
Besides I guess that `Typed Array`s are implemented as actual heap memory, which will be slower than using stack.

Comment: But knowing that you have asm.js maybe you could actually use a more convenient implementation of the `Typed Array`, like actually use stack..?

Comment: @Inuart this could probably be done. The problem is that it is a huge undertaking and also, that the stack has to be accessed by via `Typed Array` interfaces. So you at least will always have that delegation overhead.

Comment: What do you mean that the stack is a typed array, regular code seems to be running on the javascript stack?

Answer (score 1):

Because Firefox's compiler doesn't do as many optimizations which benefit asm.js code as C compilers do.
On Windows, also because compiled code has to perform bounds checks for array access (on other OSes OdinMonkey, Firefox's asm.js compiler, uses memory protection).

Comment: So you believe that running at, say, 95% speed is possible (like in NaCl)?

Comment: NaCl code can use SIMD instructions, which asm.js doesn't have. (PNaCl will probably have the same problem.)  Firefox doesn't do auto-vectorization either. But asm.js spec isn't final (it's even planned to disable asm.js support in Firefox 22 when it reaches beta, that is, asm.js code will be treated as ordinary JS in that version) so in the future, _maybe_ asm.js compilers will auto-vectorize (so far no free compiler does that well) or  asm.js will be extended.